# Как вывести строку DataGridRow в панели группировки?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть такой DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" IsReadOnly="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="False">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander>

                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

В данном случае он выводит некую коллекцию `ListCollectionView`. Так же добавлена группировка по некоему столбцу типа `string`. В заголовке группировки отображается значение этого столбца и кнопочка экспандера. Вопрос, а как вместо имени вывести строку таблицы, в которой будут применены некоторые агрегатные функции к значениям других столбцов?